# Eyefinity with lower power graphic card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, eyefinity

I am looking for a graphic that supports Eyefinity, but with lower power. What I mean by "lower power" is lower performance and lower power literally. I don't need performance and heat of ATI 5 Series, but I love their multi-monitor supports and price range.

What options do I have?

Comment: wait until ATI rolls out budget Dx11 cards with Eyefinity support ... :)

Comment: @Molly // are they going to release such card?

Answer (score 3):

Eyefinity is a technology included in all of ATI's new 5xxx cards, no other cards have Eyefinity tech. From cheapest/least performance first the options are as follows.

5750
5770
5850
5870
5970

The 5 series cards are quite power conscious too. Your choice should depend on what your wanting to do with the setup, gaming or office work?

There is also the Matrox triple-head-to-go that can power three monitors but grabbing a 57xx is going to be easier/cheaper.

Another thing to consider is that with Eyefinity one of your monitors needs a display port connection.

More info here... http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?t=18086706

Answer (score 2):

The ATI Radeon HD 5670 has Eyefinity support and is pretty cheap (under 100$).

Engadget has an article about it: **[ATI Radeon HD 5670 brings DirectX 11 and Eyefinity to the budget-minded market](http://www.engadget.com/2010/01/14/ati-radeon-hd-5670-brings-directx-11-and-eyefinity-to-the-budget/)**

Answer (score 0):

Q: What options do I have?

A: None. Eyefinity is only integrated in the ATI 5xxx series, period.

You can wait and hope for ATI to release "budget" 5xxx serie with Eyefinity support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (any of this with DisplayPort, for 6 monitors card must have 2 DisplayPorts):

- AMD 7450 (up to 4, 18W)
- AMD 7570 (up to 4, 44W)
- AMD 7730 (up to 6, 47W)
- AMD 8450 (up to 4, 18W)
- AMD 8730 (47W)

Power consumption form [here](http://www.eggxpert.com/forums/thread/493743.aspx)